# Pass product variable Shopify to snippet

Tags: shopify, product, render, code-snippets, assign

**Set-up**

I have a Shopify shop with the Debut theme.

In the `product-card-grid.liquid` file of the theme, I have adjusted/added the following code to add extra lines per product card in the collection grid,

```
<div class="h4 grid-view-item__title product-card__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ product.title }}</div>

{% include 'product-price' incl. BTW, variant: product.selected_or_first_available_variant, product: product, show_vendor: show_vendor %}  

{%- if  product.price > 10000 and product.price < 25000 -%}        
  <font size = "2">Of renteloos 3x <strong>{{ product.price | divided_by:3 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong></font>
{%- elsif  product.price > 25000 -%}
  <font size = "2">Of gespreid vanaf <strong>{{ product.price | times: 0.03287 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong> p/m</font>
{%- endif -%}
```

which works fine.

---

**Issue**

If I create the snippet `own-collection-grid-spreadpayment.liquid` which looks like,

```
{%- if  product.price > 10000 and product.price < 25000 -%}        
    <font size = "2">Of renteloos 3x <strong>{{ product.price | divided_by:3 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong></font>
{%- elsif  product.price > 25000 -%}
    <font size = "2">Of gespreid vanaf <strong>{{ product.price | times: 0.03287 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong> p/m</font>
{%- endif -%}
```

and then try to render the snippet in the `product-card-grid.liquid` like so,

```
<div class="h4 grid-view-item__title product-card__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ product.title }}</div>

{% include 'product-price' incl. BTW, variant: product.selected_or_first_available_variant, product: product, show_vendor: show_vendor %}  

{%- render 'own-collection-grid-spreadpayment' -%}
```

the extra lines per product don't show.

---

**Tries**

I'm aware that variables should be passed to a snippet like so,

```
{%- assign my_variable:'product' -%}      
{%- render 'own-collection-grid-spreadpayment', my_variable:my_variable  -%}
```

but still, the extra lines per product don't show.

Either I'm doing the above wrong, or it has to do with the `product` variable itself being special or something.

---

**Question**

How do I,

1. Pass the `product` variable correctly to the snippet, and;
2. How do I render the snippet with the `product` variable correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has something I have never seen before which is `incl. BTW`

regardless, this is [shopify theme-tags](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/theme-tags#render)

assign variable with `=` not `:`,
you are passing a `string` to `my_variable`, not an `object` of course it will not hold product data.

```
{% assign my_variable = product %}

{% render 'own-collection-grid-spreadpayment' with my_variable %}
```

or

```
{% render 'own-collection-grid-spreadpayment' with product, a: a, b: b %}
```

`own-collection-grid-spreadpayment.liquid`

```
{% assign product = own-collection-grid-spreadpayment %}
{%- if  product.price > 10000 and product.price < 25000 -%}        
    <font size = "2">Of renteloos 3x <strong>{{ product.price | divided_by:3 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong></font>
{%- elsif  product.price > 25000 -%}
    <font size = "2">Of gespreid vanaf <strong>{{ product.price | times: 0.03287 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</strong> p/m</font>
{%- endif -%}
```